# Modify Page Title before output via wp_page_list

Tags: pages, list

HI all,
I need to change the title of some pages before they are output on a list via wp_list_page.
I don't want to change the page title in the backend
To be clear, my list displays
 `$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0&exclude=&depth=1");`
Intro
Page 1
Page 2
Page 3

I need to change the name of Intro to be Special

Thx
s

Answer (score 1):

Very crude way of doing it:

```
<?php
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0&exclude=&depth=1");
$children = str_replace("Intro", "Special", $children);
?>
```

Or alternatively you can look at using the new menus feature in WordPress 3.0. Build up you menu of pages, and in there you can assign a different menu name to the page title.

http://en.support.wordpress.com/menus/